# Is this proof regarding odd perfect numbers correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$.  (That is, $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.)  Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of the divisors* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define
$$D(n^2) := 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$$
to be the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the non-Euler part $n^2$.

**CLAIM**

> $\gcd(n^2, D(n^2)) \neq 1$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

From this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01868.pdf), we have the relationships

$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \dfrac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}.$$

We also have the lower bound

$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \geq 3.$$

Since $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, ax+by)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have

$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2, 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2, D(n^2)) \geq 3.$$

Here is my question:

**QUESTION**

> Is this proof correct?

**Added February 13 2017**

Note that, for the Descartes spoof $d = 198585576189 = KM$ (where $K$ is a square and $M$ is the quasi-Euler prime), then
$$D(K) = D({3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}) = 819 = {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}$$
which divides $K = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}$. (In other words, $K$ is an odd deficient-perfect number.)

In particular, note that
$$\gcd(K, D(K)) = {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13} = D(K) \neq 1.$$

Comment: Probably more suitable for http://www.mathoverflow.com (if I remember correctly, according to the rules of this website).

Comment: @barakmanos, thank you for your comment.  However, when I checked MO, there is no **proof-verification** tag.  Hence, I have posted my question here instead.

Comment: OK, at first glance, I thought you meant to prove an unproven conjecture.

Comment: @barakmanos I think, it [is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173314/what-is-wrong-with-this-proof-that-there-are-no-odd-perfect-numbers) meant.

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me except that the claim "$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, ax+by)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$" is not true in general. Take $a=2,b=3,x=2,y=2$. Your proof is correct because $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,2a-b)$ is true.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @mathlove! I think that will qualify as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this proof correct?

Your proof looks correct to me except that the claim "$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, ax+by)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$" is not true in general. Take $a=2,b=3,x=2,y=2$. Your proof is correct because $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,2a-b)$ is true.