# What is wrong with this proof that there are no odd perfect numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**Main Question**

> What is wrong with this proof that there are no odd perfect numbers?

**The "Proof"**

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $N$, if any exists, must take the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the Euler prime satisfying $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Denote the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ by $\sigma(x)$, and the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.  Finally, denote the abundancy index by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Consider the quantity $D(q^k)/\sigma(q^k)$:
$$\dfrac{D(q^k)}{\sigma(q^k)}=\dfrac{D(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\dfrac{1}{I(q^k)}=\dfrac{1}{I(q^k)}\cdot\bigg(2-I(q^k)\bigg)=I(n^2)-1.$$
Multiplying both sides by $n^2$, we get
$$\dfrac{D(q^k)\cdot{n^2}}{\sigma(q^k)}=\sigma(n^2)-n^2 \in \mathbb{N}.$$
It is easy to show the following claims:

**Claim 1** $\sigma(q^k) \nmid D(q^k)$

*Proof* Suppose to the contrary that $\sigma(q^k) \mid D(q^k)=2q^k - \sigma(q^k)$.  This implies that $\sigma(q^k) \leq 2q^k - \sigma(q^k)$, which contradicts $q^k + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k)$.  **QED**

**Claim 2** $\sigma(q^k) \nmid n^2$

*Proof* Suppose to the contrary that $\sigma(q^k) \mid n^2$.  Then
$$\dfrac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{2q^k}$$
is an integer, contradicting the fact that $\sigma(n^2)$ is odd.  **QED**

Hence, $\sigma(q^k) \nmid \bigg(D(q^k)\cdot{n^2}\bigg)$, contradicting
$$\dfrac{D(q^k)\cdot{n^2}}{\sigma(q^k)}=\sigma(n^2)-n^2 \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142216/is-this-proof-regarding-odd-perfect-numbers-correct).

Comment: Without studying the details, knowing that $a \,  \nmid\, b $ and $a \,  \nmid \, c $ does not in general imply that $a \,  \nmid \, bc $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$D(q^k)\cdot{n^2} = \bigg(2q^k - \sigma(q^k)\bigg)\cdot{n^2} = 2{q^k}{n^2} - \sigma(q^k){n^2}$$ 
$$= \sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) - \sigma(q^k){n^2} = \sigma(q^k)\cdot\bigg(\sigma(n^2) - n^2\bigg)$$
which is divisible by $\sigma(q^k)$.

Therefore, there is no contradiction.